# sqlite / websql: separate queries produce different results than join queries

Tags: sql, sqlite, web-sql

I have a very simple db that has two tables, one to store a user's auth (username and pw) and one to store preferences. Currently when my app initializes, it checks for settings first and then auth. But I want to grab it all at once. The way the app is designed, there is only ever 1 record in either table, so I don't use WHERE clauses in my queries.

The problem is, when I do queries separately, they give different results than if I join them.

Consider this scenario: a user logs in, sets some settings and then logs out. In may app this causes the auth table to be cleared but the settings remain intact.

Sign-out query (just clears auth table)

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM userdata');
}, errorDB);
```

However this outputs "0 rows found":

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT USERDATA.*, PREFS.* FROM USERDATA, PREFS', [], function (tx, results) {
         var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log(len + " rows found.");
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i));
        }
    }, errorDB);
}, errorDB);
```

Whereas this outputs a row:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PREFS', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log(len + " rows found.");
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i));
        }
    }, errorDB);
}, errorDB);
```

Even if there is no auth shouldn't the join query find the prefs data? What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you list two tables A and B in the `FROM` clause, you get a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), which returns A×B records.
So if one table is empty, the result will be empty, too.

To ensure that you have a record even for an empty table, add another record with [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound), then use LIMIT 1 return the first record.
For example,

```
SELECT Name, PW FROM UserData
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL
LIMIT 1
```

will return either a single record with the name/password, or a single record with two NULL values.

To join that with the other table, use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Name, PW FROM UserData
      UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL, NULL
      LIMIT 1),
     Prefs
```